# DropBox upload using files_put returns authentication failed

Tags: c++, c, libcurl, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload a file (simple text file with one line of text in it) using with my C/C++ application using libCurl.

There are a few things that I have noticed.

First...

The DropBox API appears to want a '&' instead of a '?' before the list of arguments.

Second...

It is unclear if the body of the request needs to be included in computing the oauth_signature.

Ultimately, I get an "Authentication failed" response from the DropBox API.

I've included the debug trace from libCurl for more information...

```
SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
About to connect() to api-content.dropbox.com port 443 (#0)
Trying 107.22.243.22... Connected to api-content.dropbox.com (107.22.243.22) port 443 (#0)
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server certificate:
subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Dropbox, Inc.; OU=IT; CN=*.dropbox.com
start date: 2010-01-06 00:00:00 GMT
expire date: 2012-01-06 23:59:59 GMT
common name: *.dropbox.com (matched)
issuer: C=ZA; ST=Western Cape; L=Cape Town; O=Thawte Consulting cc; OU=Certification     Services Division; CN=Thawte Premium Server CA; emailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com
SSL certificate verify ok.
PUT         /1/files_put/dropbox/1&file=test%2Etxt&overwrite=true&oauth_consumer_key=asfewasdfas&oauth_nonce=1323293220d0&oauth_signature=asmoa4YE2c%2FuwjDKJRKFILpcn8%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1323293220&oauth_token=fafsesnj13iguxnh&oauth_version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: api-content.dropbox.com
Accept: */*
Content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 24
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Test upload to DropBox.
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: dbws
Date: Wed, 07 Dec 2011 21:27:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

22
{"error": "Authentication failed"}
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OAuth ["PLAINTEXT"](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor22) authentication mode using the [HTTP "Authorization" header](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#auth_header).

PLAINTEXT OAuth is much less error prone (since there's no canonicalizattion or hashing).